# How to query and display a single record in a lightning web component?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

i'm transitioning from LAC to LWC and am finding it a bit of a struggle to understand some of the basics.

Just an example project is, I have object "Pet__c" and child object "Pet_Meal__c"
I want to have the web component display the most recent "Pet_Meal__c" record information on the "Pet__c" record page.

In aura I would have just called a function in the Apex Controller then assigned it to an attribute with
`"component.set('v.LatestMeal', response.getReturnValue());"`

Then displayed it via`{!v.LatestMeal.Name}`

In LWC i'm managing to get the the record in the "result" variable.

```
@wire(getPetMeal, { LocationRecordId : '$recordId' }) actionGetMeal(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Returns

```
data: Object {…}
Name: 'Beef Chunks'
Id: "a01Qy000009duOXIAY"
Calories__c: 600
Price__c: 5.25
```

But when I try and display it with {mealInfo.Name} nothing is coming up.

**Full snippet below:**

Javascript

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getPetMeal from '@salesforce/apex/petUtilitiesController.getLatestMeal';

export default class mealFinder extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId; 
    mealInfo; 

    @wire(getPetMeal , { LocationRecordId : '$recordId' }) actionGetMeal(result) {
        console.log(result); //This debugs the record correctly.
        if (result) {
            this.mealInfo = result; //This assignment appears to not work.
        } 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    HELLO WORLD <!-- This works -->
    {recordId} <!-- This works -->
    {mealInfo.Name} <!-- This displays nothing -->
</template>
```

Comment: Wires return null or an object with `data` or `error` properties. You probably want to set `this.mealInfo = result.data;`. However, you need to check for errors or null result as well, and you probably should use the standard record API wire service instead of writing your own apex. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-record.html) for details and example code.

Comment: Does the standard method support using recordId as a relationship reference rather than the direct query? The current query I use is [Select x,y,z from Pet_Meal__c where Pet__c =: petId]

Comment: Not using getRecord. However, the page I linked to still has value; look at the last example where you can see how `error` and `data` are used from the wire result - this is what you need to handle, even with a custom apex wire.

Comment: More detail on how to handle wires is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-wire-service-about.html). It always pays to do a bit of research via Internet search.

Comment: Oh, one last thing: [graphQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-graphql.html) should let you avoid custom apex code.